# How do you pass an object array to an Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, bundle

I have read posts on passing arrays from and to activities, but I am confused as to how I would do it for my specific case.

I have an array of objects called DaysWeather (a DaysWeather[] array) where the objects have several String attributes as well as a bitmap attribute.  I read somewhere that you have to make it serializable or parceable or something, but it seems messy at first glance.

Could someone lead me in the right direction?

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your objects need to implement the [Parcelable interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

When this is done, you can create the Parcelable array and pass it to the activity:

```
// We assume we have an array: DaysWeather[] input;
Parcelable[] output = new Parcelable[input.length];
for (int i=input.length-1; i>=0; --i) {
    output[i] = input[i];
}

Intent i = new Intent(...);
i.putExtra("myArray", output);
```

Also note that when you implement the Parcelable interface, do not serialize full heavy objects. For instance, for your bitmap, serialize the ressource ID only and when inflating, recreate the bitmap from the ressource ID.

Comment: But don't do this. Use other methods to transfer objects such as a service.

Comment: Another way to pass objects between activities is to use content providers, broadcast receivers and intent filters. (http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/)

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say "do not serialize full heavy objects."  My bitmaps do not have resource ID's as they are downloaded from the web directly into their respective container objects.  Also, can you direct me to a suitable tutorial/example of implementing Parcelable?  My objects (DaysWeather) are simply data structures containing 5 strings and a bitmap.  I'm not exactly sure how to implement the writeToParcel() method with this data.

Comment: For the strings, simply use parcel.writeString and parcel.readString methods. Concerning the bitmap, what I meant is you don't serialize (write) the image (the image bytes) but rather, you will serialize the image URL or the cached file location on the SDCard. When you will deserialize (read) the object, you will get the URL or path for the image and recreate your bitmap accordingly. This way you don't serialize kilobytes of data but rather a few bytes. Concerning the tutorials, just Google and read the ones on the first result page. The explanations on the Parcelable class page are also good.