# passing 2d array to a new activity in android

Tags: android, multidimensional-array, android-activity

How to pass a **`2d String array`** to **`new activity`**???

and then in new activity, How can i **`retrieve`** the array??

Comment: check: [Pass 2D array to another Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214847/pass-2d-array-to-another-activity), [Android - How to pass a double array between activities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214847/pass-2d-array-to-another-activity)

Comment: You can try this link . hope this will help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181885/how-do-you-pass-an-object-array-to-an-activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use:

```
 String [][]str;
 Intent summaryIntent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
 Bundle b=new Bundle();
 b.putSerializable("Array", str);
 summaryIntent.putExtras(b);
 startActivity(summaryIntent);
```

For Recieving the Array use:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String[][] list_array = (String[][])b.getSerializable("Array");
```

Thanks

Comment: i have got error on this line String[][] list_array = (String[][])b.getSerializable("Array");

Comment: @ AppMobiGurmeet i don't know it gives force close error on this line

Comment: @Dawood Ahmad:This is because [][]str is empty.Due to this it may be giving a null pointer exception.Add some data and then check for the result.Can you please provide logs for more clear understanding?.Thanks

Comment: String[][] array = new String[][]
  {
  { "a", "abc" },
  { "b", "bcd" },
  { "c", "cde" },
  { "d", "def" },
  { "f", "fgh" }, };

  final Intent summaryIntent = new Intent(this, NewTest.class);
  Bundle b = new Bundle();
  b.putSerializable("Array", array);
  summaryIntent.putExtras(b);

Comment: you can use this  Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArray(key, new String[]{value1, value2});
Intent i=new Intent(context, Class);
i.putExtras(b);   for Reading:                                  Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] array=b.getStringArray(key);